# How to batch read and then write a list of weblink .JSON files to specified locations on C drive in Python v2.7

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, batch-processing

I have a long list of .json files that I need to download to my computer.  I want to download them as .json files (so no parsing or anything like that at this point).

I have some code that works for small files, but it is pretty buggy.  Also it doesn't handle multiple links well.

Appreciate any advice to fix up this code:

```
import os

filename = 'test.json'
path = "C:/Users//Master"
fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)


import urllib2

url = 'https://www.premierlife.com/secure/index.json'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
webContent = response.read()

f = open(fullpath, 'w')
f.write(webContent)
f.close
```

Comment: what specifically is wrong with your code and what specifically are you asking for?  If you have a list of files, where is the code that processes the list?

Comment: What is wrong with code:  Sometimes it just creates a blank file and sometimes it cuts a file off before finishing.  As for the list, I have just been copying the code many times over using excel to create the code.  I am guessing Python has better functionality for this, but I am not sure what it is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a blank file because the `f.close` at the end should be `f.close()`.

I took your code and made a little function and then called it on a little loop to go through a .txt file with the list of urls called "list_of_urls.txt" having 1 url per line (you can change the delimiter in the split function if you want to format it differently).

```
def save_json(url):
  import os

  filename = url.replace('/','').replace(':','') 
  # this replaces / and : in urls

  path = "C:/Users/Master"
  fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

  import urllib2

  response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  webContent = response.read()

  f = open(fullpath, 'w')
  f.write(webContent)
  f.close()
```

And then the loop:

```
f = open('list_of_urls.txt')
p = f.read()
url_list = p.split('\n') #here's where \n is the line break delimiter that can be changed
for url in url_list:
  save_json(url)
```

Comment: This is a great solution!  Thanks.  Do you know of a good way to incorporate a simplejson decoder into this so that I can easily parse the JSON files and then save them as something else like CSV or text?  Link:  http://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/